# Laravel Subquery Value From hasmany Relation Value

Tags: mysql, laravel, subquery, laravel-query-builder

I have a model

`Logbook` and a model
`LogbookEntries`

Logbook `hasMany` LogbookEntries and LogbookEntries `belongsto` Logbook (out of the scope of the question though). In my `LogbookEntries` I have two fields (plus others): `start date` and `end_date`. I want to show all LogbookEntries which the following date entry as an example.

**ENTRY 1**

```
start_date: 01 Mar 19
end_date: 05 Mar 19
```

**ENTRY 2**

```
start_date: 06 Mar 19
end_date: 12 Mar 19
```

**ENTRY 3**

```
start_date: 19 Jun 19
end_date: 22 Jun 19
```

If I say show all which have a follow-up date, then only Entry 3 will display. My issue is:

```
Logbook::whereHas('LogbookEntries', function($q) {
    $q->where('start_date', <???.end_date + 1 day>)
})
```

Comment: mistake: $q->where('start_date ', <???.end_date+ 1 day>)

Comment: Can you clarify what you are expecting? I don't understand what you are wanting as an output? Is it you want all Entries where the start_date was 2 days before the end_date?

Comment: all I want is entries with an immediate follow up date. so if there is an entry which has an end date of 5 mar 19, and an entry which have a start date of 6 mar 19 - then it will give me 5 mar 19, because that entry has a follow up date of 6 mar

Comment: Just to be clear, you only want the query to return entries where the end_date is the day the immediately follows the start_date? So start_date 01 Jan 2019 end_date 02 Jan 2019 would be returned but start_date 01 Jan 2019 end_date 03 Jan 2019 would NOT be returned?

Comment: yup thats all i need

Comment: What format are the dates stored in the Database?

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD aka date('Y-m-d') aka 2019-10-25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This worked for me:

If I understand your question correctly then I think the easiest way to achieve this would be with the following:

> Note the use of whereraw instead of where so that we can use direct
>   mySql code

```
Logbook::whereHas('LogbookEntries', function($q) {
    $q->whereraw('date_format(date(end_date),"%Y-%m-%d") = date_format(date(start_date),"%Y-%m-%d") + interval 1 day')
})
```

I tested this on my system and it worked a charm. However, my timestamps were in the format Y-m-d HH:mm:ii so I needed the date_format to change them. You may not need this. Therefore, you may want to also try the following:

```
Logbook::whereHas('LogbookEntries', function($q) {
    $q->whereraw('date(end_date) = date(start_date) + interval 1 day')
})
```

As this would be a lot tidier.

---

Basically what we are doing is getting entries where the end_date is the same as the start_date + 1 day. You were close but just not quite there.

My system so you can see it working:

### Without the whereraw statement:

```
>>> Task::Select('start_date','end_date')->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3325
     all: [
       App\Task {#3307
         start_date: "2018-12-20 08:00:00",
         end_date: null,
       },
       App\Task {#3291
         start_date: "2018-12-18 00:00:00",
         end_date: "2018-12-19 00:00:00",
       },
       App\Task {#3318
         start_date: "2018-12-19 00:00:00",
         end_date: "2019-01-03 00:00:00",
       },
       App\Task {#3319
         start_date: "2018-12-20 00:00:00",
         end_date: "2018-12-21 00:00:00",
       },
       App\Task {#3310
         start_date: "2018-12-20 00:00:00",
         end_date: "2018-12-21 00:00:00",
       },
       App\Task {#3317
         start_date: "2018-12-20 14:43:16",
         end_date: "2018-12-21 14:43:16",
       },
       App\Task {#3316
         start_date: "2018-12-20 14:45:27",
         end_date: "2018-12-27 14:45:27",
       },
       App\Task {#3315
         start_date: "2018-12-20 14:46:48",
         end_date: "2018-12-24 14:46:48",
       },
       App\Task {#3313
         start_date: "2018-12-21 09:25:24",
         end_date: "2018-12-24 09:25:24",
       },
       App\Task {#3298
         start_date: "2019-01-02 08:10:19",
         end_date: "2019-01-16 08:10:19",
       },
     ],
   }
```

### With the whereraw statement:

```
>>> Task::Select('start_date','end_date')->whereraw('date_format(date(end_date),"%Y-%m-%d") = date_format(date(start_dat
e),"%Y-%m-%d") + interval 1 day')->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3314
     all: [
       App\Task {#3312
         start_date: "2018-12-18 00:00:00",
         end_date: "2018-12-19 00:00:00",
       },
       App\Task {#3309
         start_date: "2018-12-20 00:00:00",
         end_date: "2018-12-21 00:00:00",
       },
       App\Task {#3320
         start_date: "2018-12-20 00:00:00",
         end_date: "2018-12-21 00:00:00",
       },
       App\Task {#3329
         start_date: "2018-12-20 14:43:16",
         end_date: "2018-12-21 14:43:16",
       },
     ],
   }
```

Comment: Peta from North East England; Can I let you in on something big? Yes? You. are. legend. Thanx man.I can work from that. Thanx so much!